# Validating foreign key constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

I have two tables `data_elements` and `types`. Types used to store a static list of types and has two columns: `id` and `name`. `data_elements` has `type` column that should be referencing `id` in `types` table. When `DataElement` is created via HTML form, the list of types is shown as drop down, and everything works. I need to create `DataElement` via api call, and I would like to validate that the `type` passed as a parameter to REST call is in fact one of types that are stored in `types` table. I haven't been able to figure out the way to do it. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

#### Model way (with validation)

If you want to handle this on the model side, I suggest you to create a "custom attribute", in this way you won't impact existing functionality for the existing `type` field. Something along these lines:

**app/models/data_element.rb**

```
def type_name=(value)
  found_type = Type.find_by(name: value.to_s)
  self.type  = found_type unless found_type.nil?
end

def type_name
  type.try(:name)
end
```

**app/controllers/data_elements_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @data_element = DataElement.new(data_element_params)
  @data_element.save
end

def data_element_params
  # Please ensure that `type` is not present in `permit`
  params.require(:data_element).permit(:whatever, :type_name, :other_field)
end
```

In this way, you handle `type_name` like if it was an attribute. You don't even need validation: if no `Type` is found for that name, you just don't change the value (you can actually report errors or even validate, in any case).

Obviously, if you use `type` too, so something like `@data_element.update_attributes(type_name: 'foo', type: Type.first)` you'll end up with weird results (`type` assignment comes after so you'll end up with `Type.first` instead of a `Type` named `'foo'`), so if you use `type_name` in the assignment, ensure `type` is not used in that moment, but shouldn't be a problem, just don't put it in `permit` params

#### Controller way

My first suggestion is "do not use type" as table/model name. The `type` column is usually used by Rails for Single Table Inheritance, that's the main reason. Even calling it DataElementType would already be ok, but in any case this is your choice.

About your question, there are various ways to do that, the first one that come up in my mind is

**app/models/type.rb**

```
class Type
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end
```

**app/controllers/data_elements_controller.rb**

```
def create
  # Please add an index to `name` column and ensure is a unique one
  type = Type.find_by(name: params[:type].to_s)
  if type.nil?
    head :unprocessable_entity
  else
    @data_element = DataElement.new(data_element_params.merge(type: type))
    if @data_element.save
      #dosomething
    end
  end
end
```

You might want to refactor the method a bit, but this sure gives you a general idea.

Comment: thank you!  the actual name of the column is de_type. I guess I tried to keep it simple in describing the model. This definitely helps. I was thinking that there is got to be a way to make it work automatically  via using either "validate" or just by defining the relationships (has_one, or belongs_to) between objects. I guess not. I will do what you are suggesting.

Comment: There is a way definitely, not completely automatic, but will use `validate`, let me update the answer ;)

Comment: @ Fire-Dragon-DoL, EveDreamer, you guys are awesome! thank you. I've been dealing with Ruby for only a week, so I very much appreciate all the extra details. Now, why the hell is my name is "user3038783"? I'd better change that:-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Fire-Dragon-DoL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312907/fire-dragon-dol) that `type` is not recommended to use as it's usually used by STI. In your case, if you will not store too many data in `types` table, I recommend you define a constant like `ELEMENT_TYPES` which is a array contains all the types you would use in `DataElement` model. And then you add a validation like

```
class DataElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :type, inclusion: { in: ELEMENT_TYPES }`
end
```

If so, you can avoid writing redundant logic to validate the `type` attribute when a data_element object will be saved.

You can use [options_for_select(container, selected = nil)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) method to complete your select box. If the option value and option name is the same, what you should do is just replace `container` argument with `DataElement::ELEMENT_TYPES`. If not, you'd better define a helper method like:

```
def types_container
  DataElement::ELEMENT_TYPES.map do |type|
    [DataElement.human_attribute_name(type), type]
  end
end
```

and then just replace `container` argument with `types_container` helper method. This should be your choice if you want to translate the type's value. And if this is what you need, you may have to know something called [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) in rails.
Wish my answer could help.

**Updated:**
well, if you insist to use db to store your data, it is not difficult to meet the need.
I suppose that a `type` has many `data_elements`, and your schema will look like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150708021148) do

  create_table "data_elements", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "de_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

(you may need to add index or something like on `de_type` to improve query efficiency)

At first, define the association relationship in your DataElement and Type model:

**app/models/type.rb**

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :data_elements
end
```

**app/models/data_element.rb**

```
class DataElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type, foreign_key: 'de_type'
end
```

This will make you easy to get a `type` object via a `data_element` or get `data_elements` via `type`.

Then you just need to add a validation to you `DataElement` model:

```
validates :type, presence: true
```

This validation will fail the update or create if the `de_type` does not exist in the id collection of `types` table.

I will show you how it works in my rails console:

```
2.1.1 :006 >   Type.all
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<Type id: 1, name: "type1", created_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:33", updated_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:33">, 
#<Type id: 2, name: "type2", created_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:38", updated_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:38">, 
#<Type id: 3, name: "type3", created_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:39", updated_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:39">, 
#<Type id: 4, name: "type4", created_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:41", updated_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:41">, 
#<Type id: 5, name: "type5", created_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:43", updated_at: "2015-07-08 02:17:43">
]>
```

You could find that I've created some records for `types`. Now I will try to create some data_elements:

```
2.1.1 :009 >   DataElement.create!(de_type: 7)

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Type can't be blank
```

well, as you see, I tried to create a data_element whose `de_type` is **7**. And you could not find a `type` record whose id is 7, right? So you finally see that RecordInvalid error was raised and the error info is `Type can't be blank`.

Now, let us create a data_element without any error:

```
2.1.1 :010 > DataElement.create!(de_type: 2)
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Type Load (131.0ms)  SELECT  "types".* FROM "types" WHERE "types"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "data_elements" ("de_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["de_type", 2], ["created_at", "2015-07-08 03:05:51.046949"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-08 03:05:51.046949"]]
   (6.3ms)  commit transaction
 => #<DataElement id: 4, de_type: 2, created_at: "2015-07-08 03:05:51", updated_at: "2015-07-08 03:05:51">
```

So, the record was successfully created, interesting?
You can find more info in rails guide (sorry that I can't post more than 2 links)

Comment: thank you. are you suggesting using a constant ELEMENT_TYPES instead of storing it in the table or populating it with data from the table.? I would much prefer it to be stored in the database in case it will have to be referenced by something else.